# Android on click listener to pass json variables

Tags: android, events, click, listener

I have a ListView and  Iwant it so that, when you click on an item in the list it takes you to another activity, but with the variable of what I clicked.

For example, ifIi have item1, item2, item3 I want it so that, when i click on item1 it takes me to another activity and in that other activity everything that would be inside item1, in the json feed, gets displayed .

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ChooseTeamActivity extends ListActivity {
    public String FullData = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.chooseact);
    final String FullData = getIntent().getStringExtra("FullData");
    Log.v("lc", "chooseActivity:" + FullData);
    try{

   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(FullData);
   List<String> leagues = new ArrayList<String>();


   JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");

   JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("structure");



   for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
   {     JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);   

    JSONArray DivisionsArray = oneObject.getJSONArray("divisions");



    for (int d=0; d < DivisionsArray.length(); d++){

        JSONObject DivDict = DivisionsArray.getJSONObject(d);   
        leagues.add(DivDict.getString("name"));
    }

   }
   setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, leagues));

   ListView list = getListView();

    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) arg1).getText(),1000).show();
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChooseTeamActivity.class);
            nextScreen.putExtra("FullData", FullData);
            startActivity(nextScreen);
        }
        });

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: The interesting code is the caller activity. please post its code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a field reference to DivisionArray, then override onListItemClicked to get the index of the clicked item, then look up that item in DivisionArray:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // TODO: Add code here to look up the item in DivisionArray by index, then use
    // that to launch an activity either with the index or the JSON structure as an extra
}
```

Once you have the index, you can launch an activity with the index, or the JSON structure:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("selectedItem", /* TODO: use the index to the item or the JSON structure itself here */);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the click event handler:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { 

}
```

And add code there for fire your activity with a parameter (your json stuff for example, or a way to get it)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedActivity.class);
//leagues.get(position);
//or just use the position:
foo.putExtra("itemIndex", position);
//foo.putExtra("fullData", FullData); //or just the part you want
startActivity(foo);
```

Comment: this says void is an invalid type for the variable onListItemClick

Comment: Then you didn't copy and paste correctly, such as in the wrong place? DO it before the last "}" in your file for example.

Comment: do i still need list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {} in there if i add this. ps apologies i wasn't put it in the right place

Comment: No. You can do it either way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `setOnItemClickListener()` method and use intents to pass the String of the Data that is to be displayed as follows on the list

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                     int position, long id) {
                          Bundle b = new Bundle();
                          b.putString("itemData",data[poition]);
                          Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                          intent.putExtras(b);
                          startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Here the data[] is an array of strings which contains the data that is to be passed from Activity1 to Activity2. Activity 1 is the current activity and you can fix Activity2 also, just populate it with different data.

Comment: I've had to edit this bait because e it had errors is this correct  
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
                      Bundle b = new Bundle();
              Object[] data = null;
b.putString("itemData", (String) data[position]);
                      Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseTeamActivity.this,SelectTeamActivity.class);
                      intent.putExtras(b);
                      startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

Comment: Its difficult to understand without the formatting, but it seems correct. Just store the proper JSON string in the data string array.

Comment: When you are parsing the JSON response in the for loop, just store the response as string in the data[] string array.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code.**

```
    yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long arg3) 
        {


            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NotesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Date", "Item To Pass In Ur Activity");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**On your Activity write the following code to get the item that are pass by your listview**

```
String selectedDate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Date");
```